# append inside a foreach in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, foreach, append

Hi friends i use a foreach and inside i show html with `.append`, this is when i execute a modal, this is the code:

```
    $('#modalEditProducts').on('show.bs.modal', () => {
    arrayProducts.forEach((q) =>{
        $('#modalHERE')
        .append('<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">'+
                  '<img src="'+q.photo+'" width="40%">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div style="width: 70%;">'+
                 '<form>'+  
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                      '<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">valor 1:</label>'+
                      '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor1" id="recipient-name">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                      '<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">valor 2:</label>'+
                      '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor2" id="recipient-name">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">valor 3:</label>'+
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor3" id="recipient-name">'+
                  '</div>'+
                 '</form>'+
                '</div>');
     })
})
```

the problem is when i close the model and i back open this, the data is show doubled... i checked my array and this is not doubled, is how if the foreach save the data, i dont know, please can you say me what its my error? or how i can solve that?

if you need more data, please i say me, thanks.

Comment: replace `.append` with `.html`

Comment: you may also consider to [empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) your container before the forEach loop: $('#modalHERE').empty();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are appending the form over and over again without clearing it first. Clear the html first then reload the loop

```
$('#modalEditProducts').on('show.bs.modal', () => {
$('#modalHERE').html('');
arrayProducts.forEach((q) =>{
    $('#modalHERE')
    .append('<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">'+
              '<img src="'+q.photo+'" width="40%">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div style="width: 70%;">'+
             '<form>'+  
                '<div class="form-group">'+
                  '<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">valor 1:</label>'+
                  '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor1" id="recipient-name">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="form-group">'+
                  '<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">valor 2:</label>'+
                  '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor2" id="recipient-name">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="form-group">'+
                '<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">valor 3:</label>'+
                '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor3" id="recipient-name">'+
              '</div>'+
             '</form>'+
            '</div>');
 })
```

})

Comment: this worked, but now only show a data and in my array i have two data

Comment: ah I see you are looping, Ill change my answer. Didn't see that loop. So you are still appending, you just need to clear the div first.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.append` with `.html`.
To add multiple elements to modal, you need to loop and create template first & then add it to modal

you are using `.append` which keeps on appending the template, So use `.html` API which replaces existing template with new one.

```
$('#modalEditProducts').on('show.bs.modal', () => {
    var template = "";
    arrayProducts.forEach((q) =>{
    template +='<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">'+
                  '<img src="'+q.photo+'" width="40%">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div style="width: 70%;">'+
                 '<form>'+  
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                      '<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">valor 1:</label>'+
                      '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor1" id="recipient-name">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                      '<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">valor 2:</label>'+
                      '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor2" id="recipient-name">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">valor 3:</label>'+
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="valor3" id="recipient-name">'+
                  '</div>'+
                 '</form>'+
                '</div>';

     })
     $('#modalHERE')
        .html(template );
}

 )
```

Comment: this worked, but now only show a data and in my array i have two data

Comment: right.. there is glitch in logic.. you want to add 2 elements to same modalHere.. you need to update your logic

Comment: in loop you were overwriting your previous changes, when `.html` is used.. else with `.append` you can check @cesars answer